# Правильная организация работы с объектами через Entity

Tags: c#, entity, solid

Я новичок в использовании  Entity и хочу реализовать такую стратегию.
Все бизнес объекты наследуются от BaseObject который в числе прочих имеет методы

```
 void Save(Transaction transaction=null);

 void Delete(Transaction transaction=null);
```

В реализации методов  Save и Delete идет получение нужного контекста и собственно действия:сохранение  или удаление.
Для получения объектов  хочу использовать фабрику классов. 
То есть в любом месте кода можно будет написать например так.

```
var order =  Facrory.Get<IOrder>(id);
order.Delete();
```

Мои коллеги по работе почему то считают такой подход неприменимым к Entity.
Якобы совершенно необходимо иметь IOrderRepositary, то есть код должен быть таким

```
var orderRepos = Facrory.Get<IOrderRepositary>();
var  order = orderRepos.getById(id); 
orderRepos.Orders.Remove(order);
orderRepos.SaveChanges();
```

Объясняют это тем, что код по работе c базой данных должен быть обязательно отделен от кода объекта ...

Действительно ли предлагаемый мой подход принципиально не соответствует принципам SOLID.

---

Правильно ли я поняла что такой метод в классе ордер может быть. и он в минимальной степени нарушет принцип SOLID?

```
public override void Delete()
    {
        var orderRepos = Facrory.Get<IOrdersRepositary>();
        var order = orderRepos.Delete(this.ID);
    }
```

Само удаление происходит в классе IOrdersRepositary Order в некотором смысле делегирует действия с базой данных IOrdersRepositary.

По сути это  Shortcut к методу orderRepos.Delete()

Таким образом при использовании Order нет необходимости знать что-либо о IOrdersRepositary.

Comment: Ну то есть вы хотите и состояние объекта хранить и работать с БД в одном классе. Как это вяжется с `S` в SOLID?

Comment: Теоретически вы привязываете контекст работы с базой данных к самому объекту, тем самым теряете чистый объект. Если вдруг вам придется передавать этот объект по сети и получать его обратно, вы можете столкнуться с проблемами: `public ActionResult Create(IOrder order) { order.Save(); /*сложная обработка внутри т.к. объект пришел не из фабрики и не имеет внутри контекста */ }`. Гораздо проще иметь промежуточный класс между IOrder и базой, к примеру паттерн репозиторий: https://metanit.com/sharp/articles/mvc/11.php и писать уже `Orders.Create(order).Save()`.

Comment: Принципы SOLID не догма, а пожелание. С одной стороны объект должен быть простым, но представьте что с объектом можно совершать множество различных действий сериализация, валидация, работа с базой и ещё что ни будь.
Вы что под каждое такое действие будете создавать отдельный публичный класс и для работы с обьектом надо знать все эти классы. API получится ужасно неудобным. Вот бы word или excel так делали. Вам нужно обеспечить удобство работы.
Объект вполне может иметь методы типа save,validate,delete... Желательно конечно что бы он делегировал эту работу другим классам.

Comment: У вас получился паттерн [Active Record](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveRecord). Имеет право на существование.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Да, но ему как раз и вменяют нарушение SRP как верно указал tym32167 - поэтому паттерн имеет право на существование, но в последние годы считают больше за антипаттерн.

Answer (score 0):

SOLID не всегда соблюдается так входит в  противоречие с удобством API.  Реальные программы всегда компромисс.
Возьмите к примеру XmlDocument 
Он имеет методы как для работы с хмл в пом числе валидация так и для сохранения в файл и т. п. То есть он имеет удобный API в котором все действия с объектом имеют общую точку входа(сам объект). Но внутри возможно каждое из этих действий делегируется правильному классу который построен с соблюдением SOLID.
Важнее иметь удобное API чем бездумно следовать принципу единой ответственности.

Comment: Повторная попытка оформить комментарий ответом, ИМХО напрасная трата времени.

Comment: Ответ Сергея меня очень даже устраивает. СПАСИБО!