# Разделение кода MVC Приложения на DAL BLL и элементарное удобство работы

Tags: c#, mvc, entity

Классическое деление MVC приложения на  DAL  BLL UI предполагает что, DAL  и BLL находятся в разных сборках и DAL ничего не должен знать о бизнес логике.

Прошу прощения за наивные вопросы. Но такое деление как мне кажется создает множество неудобств , а преимущества от него не очевидны.

Преимущества :

- Посмотрев на класс в DAL сразу понятно, что сохраняется в базу.
- Соблюдение принципа единой ответственности .

Недостатки:

- Сложно организовать наследование.
- Валидация бизнес логики через атрибуты  средствами Entity невозможна.
- Неоправданное усложнение кода.

Буду очень признательна если кто ни будь поможет решить ниже заданные вопросы просто и элегантно что бы и овцы были целы и волки сыты.

- Я хочу валидировать  Entity через атрибуты в том числе  кастомные  которые затрагивают бизнес логику. Есть ли способ валидации без смешивания слоев?
- Я хочу иметь  базовый класс  BusinessObject  обладающий общими для всех  бизнес объектов  свойствами и методами. На мой взгляд логично было бы что бы все Entity наследовались от него. Как правильно организовать код?
- По сути развитие предыдущего вопроса. Я имею общий базовый класс для некой категории бизнес объектов например BaseAgree. Он должен содержать базовую бизнес логику для всех договоров (в том числе базовые свойства). Вопрос  тот же.

Ps : по-моему класс наследник  DBContext  и является классом  ответственным за  сохранение в базу. То что в ему передается  именно бизнес объект  не является нарушением каких то там правил.

Как не старалась не смогла заставить DBContext работать через интерфейсы 
то есть такая конструкция не заработала

```
 DbSet <ISomeEntity> SomeEntities { get; }
```

Comment: MVC - это паттерн организации presentation layer, он вообще никакого отношения к bll/dal не имеет.

Answer (score 2):

В своё время я [натыкался на похожие проблемы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/766614/213987), решил тем, что перешёл с репозиториев на cqrs (пример приложения [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/953228/213987) и [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/923732/213987)).

Посмотрите [это видео](https://github.com/JasonGT/NorthwindTraders) и [само приложение](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_lwCVE_XgqI&index=7&list=LLFAXGDZ1WrEdqvPUmNRPQcA&t=0s)
Ключевая штука в нём - это [Mediatr](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR), его тоже обязательно поглядите.

Это архитектура вполне чистая, но не полностью - мне лично вполне хватает для решения практических задач. Как раз вопрос отделения DAL в ней не решён полностью:

> 21:34 There is a dependency injection to an Entity Framework
>   DbContext. The Application Layer has a high dependency to the
>   persistence Layer. I know this is addressed on 29:45, but still not a
>   purely "clean" application layer.

Если же говорить о тех вопросах, которые вы подымали.

> Я хочу валидировать Entity через атрибуты в том числе кастомные
>   которые затрагивают бизнес логику. Есть ли способ валидации без
>   смешивания слоев?

Вы хотите одним атрибутом, EF'овским, проверять сразу две вещи - правильность бизнес-логики и правильность в БД, а это нарушение принципа единой ответственности.

Когда вы осознаете противоречивость этого требования, то возможно откажетесь от мысли сделать единый атрибут для всего. Я в настоящее время для валидации бизнес-логики использую [fluent validation](https://fluentvalidation.net/start), оно не на базе атрибутов, а позволяет писать выражения; да и ограничения для EF чаще стал описывать не атрибутами, а при помощи EF Fluent API.

> Я хочу иметь базовый класс BusinessObject обладающий общими для всех
>   бизнес объектов свойствами и методами. На мой взгляд логично было бы
>   что бы все Entity наследовались от него. Как правильно организовать
>   код?

Это слишком общий вопрос. Вам ничего не мешает отнаследоваться от общей бизнес-логики, какие конкретные проблемы у вас появились? У меня вот ощущение, что вы двигаетесь в сторону God-объектов и слишком больших ответственностей за классами, но не видя ваш код (вы даже не описали ответственности, которые у вас базовые для всех бизнес-объектов) сложно определённо говорить об этом.

> По сути развитие предыдущего вопроса. Я имею общий базовый класс для
>   некой категории бизнес объектов например BaseAgree. Он должен
>   содержать базовую бизнес логику для всех договоров (в том числе
>   базовые свойства). Вопрос тот же.

Я вспомнил ваш [предыдущий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/995330/213987). Там как раз был пример, что именно вы хотите на базовый класс повесить - сохранение и удаление и удаление, с поддержкой транзакций. Если это классы бизнес-логики - то они по заветам DDD ничего не должны знать о своей персистентности. Вот в эту сторону точно ходить не советую, повторю что вам сказали в комментариях: у вас нарушается SRP и вас архитектурно тянет в сторону паттерна Active Record. Вам очень надо определиться, вам что нужно: либо удобство написания кода, либо чистота архитектуры. Пока же я бы сказал, что у вас не очень крупные проекты и вы не чусвтсвуете выгоду от использования чистых архитектур - поэтому вам они кажутся избыточными и сложными.

> То что в ему передается именно бизнес объект не является нарушением
>   каких то там правил.

А вы не передавайте в DbSet бизнес-объект. Передавайте туда класс только с полями - схему для таблицы базы данных. Да, этот класс очень-очень похож на класс бизнес-объекта, также он очень похож на dto-класс для переноса данных между слоями приложения - но это три совершенно разных ответственности и три разных класса.

> По идее правильно построенное приложение должно иметь минимум кода.

Либо вы одним атрибутом решаете две задачи и нарушаете принцип единственной ответственности, либо честно пишете два класса вместо одного (дай бог, если только два!). Вы одновременно хотите и минимум кода и одновременно хотите соблюсти разделение слоёв. И как сказано у Боба Мартина в "Чистой архитектуре" - каждый новый слой (каждая граница между слоями) не бывает бесплатна, она возможна только если появляется дополнительный код. На текущий момент у вас нет этого понимания, зачем вы это разделение слоёв делаете: на словах-то вы за принципы и слои, но на деле вы постоянно думаете о том, как написать поменьше кода и сэкономить на том, чтобы побольше ответственностей впихнуть. И пока вы это противоречие не решите - у вас будет непонимание. А понять, за что вы платите этими слоями, этим лишним кодом вы сможете тогда, когда вам придётся расширять среднее/крупное приложение - и вот тогда вы увидите, что именно заложенная архитектура определяет цену доработки. Пока это у вас лишь теория. Фигачьте побольше прототипов, побольше реальных приложений, смотрите, как и что приходится менять при расширении приложения.

Comment: Следовательно что бы соблюсти правила надо значительно усложнить код  а именно:

   -  1) Отказаться от Entity валидации. Или городить огород с вызовом сначала валидации бизнес логики а потом вызывать логику базового класса.

   -  2)  Нагородить кучу мапперов. Которые бы преобразовывали бы объект из одного типа в другой.

Comment: Да это по сути продолжение предыдущего вопроса. Я хочу понять правила Архитектуры и что то здесь не так.  По идее правильно построенное приложение должно иметь минимум кода. Код должен быть интуитивно понятен. И с ним должно быть удобно работать. То что мне предлагают  в это правило не укладывается пока. Вместо упрощения я вижу усложнение.  Причем значительное и оправданное только утверждением что так мол правильно.

Comment: У вас в корне неправильное представление. Вы можете фигачить ВЕСЬ код прямо в main, но как только вы захотите СЛОИ и РАЗДЕЛЕНИЕ СЛОЁВ - вы будете платить за каждый слой. (Подробнее в "чистой архитектуре" дядюшки Боба). Чем больше слоёв - тем БОЛЬШЕ платить и вы как уже почувствовали насколько больше и не понимаете ЗАЧЕМ. А поймёте вы именно когда начнёте писать средние и крупные приложения, даже не писать - РАСШИРЯТЬ и вот тогда-то заложенная когда-то архитектура либо будет вам помогать, либо замедлять. Может вам всё это и не нужно, а? :)

Comment: @Евгения Добавил в ответ

Comment: Погодите. Сохранением в базу не занимается класс DBContext. Он является слоем  DAL.
Я ему ДЕЛЕГИРУЮ ответственность сохранять в базу. Он имеет свой конфиг в котором прописано какие поля базы на какое свойство маппить.  Зачем нужен еще один класс посредник? Мой класс ничего не знает кто и как его будет сохранять (Атрибуты не в счет).

Answer (score 1):

> Классическое деление MVC приложения на DAL BLL UI предполагает что, DAL и BLL находятся в разных сборках и DAL ничего не должен знать о бизнес логике.

Классическое деление MVC - это деление на M, V и C. DAL и BLL - это абстрактные уровни разделения вашего приложения, которые не привязаны к MVC/MVP/MVVM/whatewer. Они могут быть как в 2 разных сборках, так и в одной сборке, так и размазаны по 10 разным сборкам.

> Прошу прощения за наивные вопросы. Но такое деление как мне кажется создает множество неудобств , а преимущества от него не очевидны.

Преимцщество одно - котлеты отделены от мух.

> Посмотрев на класс в DAL сразу понятно, что сохраняется в базу.

Зависит от реализации DAL

> Соблюдение принципа единой ответственности .

С точки зрения всего уроаня - да. С точки зрения конкретных классов уровня, разделение на BLL и DAL не гарантирует выполнение SRP для конкретных классов.

> Я хочу валидировать Entity через атрибуты в том числе кастомные которые затрагивают бизнес логику. Есть ли способ валидации без смешивания слоев?

Вализация бизнес сущностей никак не касается DAL, DAL по идее не заботит эта вализация совсем. То, что у вас какие то ограничения есть по схеме БД, это бонус, а не часть вашей бизнес логики. Потому вся ваша валидация сущностей должна быть выполнена в BLL. Представьте, что завтра у вас не будет никакого DataContext, а вы будете сохранять данные в файл. Или в память. Или на удаленный сервер. При правильном разделении, никто в вашей программе, ни MVC, ни BLL, так и не узнают, что они теперь работают с другим источником данных и всё продолжит работать.

> Я хочу иметь базовый класс BusinessObject обладающий общими для всех бизнес объектов свойствами и методами. На мой взгляд логично было бы что бы все Entity наследовались от него. Как правильно организовать код?

Вы можете творить всё, что угодно с бизнес-сущностями, DAL не должен об 
этом вообще знать. Это не ответсвенность DAL работать с вашей иерархией наследований в BLL.

> По сути развитие предыдущего вопроса. Я имею общий базовый класс для некой категории бизнес объектов например BaseAgree. Он должен содержать базовую бизнес логику для всех договоров (в том числе базовые свойства). Вопрос тот же.

Это проблемы BLL, к DAL это не имеет отношения.

> Ps : по-моему класс наследник DBContext и является классом ответственным за сохранение в базу. То что в ему передается именно бизнес объект не является нарушением каких то там правил.

DBContext - это деталь реализации DAL, DAL не заботят ваши бизнес сущности, потому DBContext'у должно быть безразлично, что вы делаете в BLL

В теории, DAL должен быть максимально простым, его функция - сохранить переданный объект в БД. Ему не надо знать об интерфейсах или классах вашей бизнес логики. Он не будет вызывать вашу бизнес логику никогда. А вот бизнес логика вызывает слой DAL, что означает, что она, как минимум, знает о существовании DAL, и должна предоставить нужные для DAL сущности на сохранение. А то, что вы делаете - вы пытаетесь DAL приспособить вот вашу логику, что означает, что при изменении вашей логики, вам придется менять и DAL - что является нарушением SOLID и вообще дичью.

Что делать?

1. Если у вас приложение мелкое, то можно нарушить всё, что хочется, лишь бы работало.
2. Если вы хотите делать правильно, то нет такого понятия, как правильная архитектура. Есть архитектура, которая удоалетворяет вашим требованиям / задаче.
3. Если вам надо прямо выделить слои DAL и BLL, то вам надо разделить ваши объекты бизнес логики и объекты для сохранения в БД, чтобы одни не зависели друг от друга.

Comment: Спасибо всем я немного разобралась.

Comment: Не знаю кто прав но: